# HTML validation works on codepen but not on my laptop or IIS

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, web

First question but I've been using the site for over 8 years so please bear with me.  All help is greatly appreciated.  I've spent a couple of days and far too many hours now on this.

I have a web page that uses the default HTML validation via the input element required. In codepen the "message" is displayed if I don't populate the field.  I added css to also make the background yellow.  In codepen everything works great but on my laptop I get the yellow background but the majority of the inputs don't show the message.  What's really strange is that some of them will give the message but the majority don't.  I even have three within the same div and one gives the message while the other two don't.  Same exact code except for the id & name.  I know it recognizes the validation error because it triggers the css to change the background (input:invalid:focus), scrolls to it but no message.

I thought maybe it was my code so I exported the codepen and ran it from the unzipped /dist folder.  Same behavior as the original code on my laptop.  I emailed codepen and when they export and run from the /dist folder all of the fields show the message for them.  I pushed it out to an IIS server and I get the same behavior as I do on my laptop, some messages display and some don't.

There aren't any errors in the console either.  I'm at a loss.  The code is too large to include and if I put a link to the codepen it forces me to include the code. I'm using Chrome 94.  I ran the HTML through the W3C markup service and no errors. The codepen HTML does contain errors from the W3C markup service but still works whereas the HTML with no errors locally doesn't.

codepen:
[codepen shows the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn9jG.png)

local (exported codepen):
[local no message but scrolls to it & changes background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN5mq.png)

Comment: You have to show the code before we can see what is wrong with the code! Perhaps you are not testing locally using a web server? Do you see `http://` or `file://` in the address bar when you test locally?

Comment: Thanks @Kokodoko.  The pen is: https://codepen.io/icwalter/pen/eYRKWYP.  I've tested by just clicking the index.html file and by running is locally on IIS Express.  It's out on a IIS server now at: https://app1.assessbest.com/ipscp/index.html.

Comment: On my laptop and a friends I don't get the validation messages in Chrome like I do in codepen.  On my iPhone I get many of the validation messages but not all.  In the codepen all are showing.

Comment: It's hard to see any error on the codepen at least. What I often do is try to isolate the error into a few lines of code that still contain the unexpected behaviour, so it's easier to figure out what exactly is wrong. Also, I hope you're not locally testing on `file://` :)